# data.table conditional Inequality join

Tags: r, join, data.table, conditional-statements

There're two sample datasets:

```
> aDT
   col1 col2 ExtractDate
1:    1    A  2017-01-01
2:    1    A  2016-01-01
3:    2    B  2015-01-01
4:    2    B  2014-01-01
> bDT
   col1 col2   date_pol Value
1:    1    A 2017-05-20     1
2:    1    A 2016-05-20     2
3:    1    A 2015-05-20     3
4:    2    B 2014-05-20     4
```

And I need:

```
> cDT
   col1 col2 ExtractDate   date_pol Value
1:    1    A  2017-01-01 2016-05-20     2
2:    1    A  2016-01-01 2015-05-20     3
3:    2    B  2015-01-01 2014-05-20     4
4:    2    B  2014-01-01         NA    NA
```

Basically, aDT left join bDT based on col1, col2 and ExtractDate >= date_pol, only keep the first match (i.e. highest date_pol). **Cartesian join not allowed** due to memory limits.

Note:
To generate sample datasets

```
aDT <- data.table(col1 = c(1,1,2,2), col2 = c("A","A","B","B"), ExtractDate = c("2017-01-01","2016-01-01","2015-01-01","2014-01-01"))
bDT <- data.table(col1 = c(1,1,1,2), col2 = c("A","A","A","B"), date_pol = c("2017-05-20","2016-05-20","2015-05-20","2014-05-20"), Value = c(1,2,3,4))
cDT <- data.table(col1 = c(1,1,2,2), col2 = c("A","A","B","B"), ExtractDate = c("2017-01-01","2016-01-01","2015-01-01","2014-01-01")
                  ,date_pol = c("2016-05-20","2015-05-20","2014-05-20",NA), Value = c(2,3,4,NA))


aDT[,ExtractDate := ymd(ExtractDate)]
bDT[,date_pol := ymd(date_pol)]
aDT[order(-ExtractDate)]
bDT[order(-date_pol)]
```

I have tried:

```
aDT[, c("date_pol", "Value") :=
      bDT[aDT, 
          .(date_pol, Value)
          ,on = .(date_pol <= ExtractDate
                ,col1 = col1
                ,col2 = col2)
          ,mult = "first"]]
```

But results are a bit weird:

```
> aDT
   col1 col2 ExtractDate   date_pol Value ##date_pol values not right
1:    1    A  2017-01-01 2017-01-01     2
2:    1    A  2016-01-01 2016-01-01     3
3:    2    B  2015-01-01 2015-01-01     4
4:    2    B  2014-01-01 2014-01-01    NA
```

Comment: Fyi `aDT[order(-ExtractDate)]` only returns the sorted data. To change the sort order in the table itself, you can do `setorder(aDT, -ExtractDate)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When i is a data.table, the columns of i can be referred to in j by using the prefix i., e.g., `X[Y, .(val, i.val)]`. Here val refers to X's column and i.val Y's. Columns of x can now be referred to using the prefix x. and is particularly useful during joining to refer to x's join columns as they are otherwise masked by i's. For example, `X[Y, .(x.a-i.a, b), on="a"]`.

```
bDT[aDT, .(col1, col2, i.ExtractDate, x.date_pol, Value),
    on = .(date_pol <= ExtractDate, col1 = col1, col2 = col2), 
    mult = "first"]
```

output

```
   col1 col2 i.ExtractDate x.date_pol Value
1:    1    A    2017-01-01 2016-05-20     2
2:    1    A    2016-01-01 2015-05-20     3
3:    2    B    2015-01-01 2014-05-20     4
4:    2    B    2014-01-01       <NA>    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach you did yourself: without explicitly mentioning the columns in your left join. This can be very helpful if you have a lot of columns on the left side of your join, so you don't have to specify them all.

The only thing you need to do is use the prefix x.

```
aDT[, c("date_pol", "Value") := bDT[aDT, on = .(date_pol <= ExtractDate, col1, col2), 
    mult = "first", .(x.date_pol, x.Value)]]
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 ExtractDate   date_pol Value
1:    1    A  2017-01-01 2016-05-20     2
2:    1    A  2016-01-01 2015-05-20     3
3:    2    B  2015-01-01 2014-05-20     4
4:    2    B  2014-01-01       <NA>    NA
```